# Entrywise expression for L2 matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

The matrix norm induced by the $\ell^2$ norm is known to be equal to the maximum singular value of the matrix.

The matrix norms induced by the $\ell^1$ and $\ell^\infty$ norms admit simple expressions of the matrix entries: max-abs-column-sum and max-abs-row-sum, respectively. However, I cannot find a corresponding expression for the $\ell^2$ norm.

Does there exist a simple expression for the induced $\ell^2$ norm on a matrix, taken as a function of the matrix's entries?

Comment: no. all those can be written $\|M\| = \displaystyle\max_{\|v\|_p  = 1} \|Mv\|_p$ with $p=1,2,\infty$, and for $p=1$ a maximiser $v$ is a vector with only one entry $=1$, and for $p=\infty$ it is a vector with constant magnitude $1$, but when $p=2$ the maximiser is a singular vector (an eigenvector when $M$ is symmetric)

Comment: The induced $l^2$ norm is the largest eigenvalue (i.e., root of characteristic polynomial) of $M^*M$, and roots of high-degree polynomials are generally not explicit.